# Little o algebra

Tags: real-analysis, limits, taylor-expansion

I have to fully understand the little o algebra. In particular let $x\to 0$, I know $o(x^2)+o(x^3)=o(x^2)$ to prove this I have thought to prove that $o(x^3)=o(x^2).$

By definition $$o(x^3)=o(x^2)\iff \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x^3)}{x^2}=0\,\,\,\ (*)$$
This is surely true since for $o(x^3)$ holds the following:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{o(x^3)}{x^3}=0$$
So in (*) I can multiply and divide by $x$ and I obtain the limit as $0$. Am I right?

Comment: The notation $o(x^3)=o(x^2)$ is dangerous, because it could be read both ways. $x^3=o(x^2)$ is true.

Comment: but if I have in a sum o(x^3) can I replace this with o(x^2)?

Comment: Yes, but what for ?

Answer (score 1):

People often use $o(f(x))$ as an adjective, but [the correct definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) of it is the set of the functions that adjective describes, i.e.$$o(f(x)):=\{g|\forall\varepsilon>0\exists x_0\forall x(x>x_0\to|g(x)|<\varepsilon f(x))\}.$$When we write $o(x^2)+o(x^3)$, this is addition in a set-theory sense, namely $\{g+h|g\in o(x^2),\,h\in o(x^3)\}$. So what you really need to prove is $o(x^3)\subseteq o(x^2)$. This actually follows from $x^3\in o(x^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$o(x^3)$ is not the same as $o(x^2)$, however if $f(x) \in o(x^3)$ as $x \to 0$ then $f(x) \in o(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, which your derivation would show. Writing $=$ here is a significantly worse abuse of notation than writing $f(x)=o(x^2)$ as we usually do.

Comment: What I would like to know is that: if I have in a sum o(x^2) and o(x^3), I can remove o(x^3) since o(x^3) surely works as o(x^2)?

Comment: @Nik If $f \in o(x^2)$ and $g \in o(x^3)$ then also $g \in o(x^2)$ so $f+g \in o(x^2)$ (since these classes are closed under finite addition).

Comment: Ok thanks! When you say" abuse of notation", for you also writing $x^4=o(x^3)$ is an abuse?

Comment: @Nik Less so, but yes, a little bit. Because it is reasonable to write $x^4=o(x^3)$ and $x^4=o(x^2)$ but not $o(x^3)=o(x^2)$, but in some sense $=$ should really be symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Ok thanks, the last question: can i write $x^2+o(x^3)=x^2+o(x^2)$?

Comment: @Nik Out of context that makes me uneasy but in the course of a larger derivation I could see that being fine.

Comment: the context is the limit as x goes to 0

Comment: @Nik I know, but I mean a little bit more context than that. *Really* the correct syntax is $f \in o(g)$, and not using that is always a little bit of abuse of notation even if it is extremely widespread and well understood.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show, that equality in $o(x^m)+o(x^n)=o(x^m)$, where $n>m$, can be used as **equality between sets** with full rights.

Firstly let's define $o(f),x\to x_0$ as set
$$\{g\colon \exists\varepsilon, \exists \delta>0,\varepsilon:U_\delta(x_0)\to \mathbb{R},\lim\limits_{x\to x_0}\varepsilon(x)=0,\forall x \in U_\delta(x_0),g(x)=f(x)\cdot\varepsilon(x) \}$$
For proof I bring two sentences

1. $o(x^m)+o(x^n)\subset o(x^m)$:
   $$x^m\varepsilon_1(x)+x^n\varepsilon_2(x)=x^m\Big(\varepsilon_1(x) + x^{n-m} \varepsilon_2(x)\Big) $$

2.$o(x^m) \subset o(x^m)+o(x^n) $:
$$x^m\varepsilon(x) = x^n\varepsilon(x)+x^m\varepsilon(x)-x^n\varepsilon(x) = x^n\varepsilon(x) + x^m\Big(\varepsilon(x) - x^{n-m} \varepsilon(x)\Big)$$

On other hand holds $o(x^m) \subset  o(x^n) $, where $n>m$, while reverse is obviously false. So,  $o(x^m) = o(x^n) $ cannot be true if we use equality between sets.

Comment: Very thanks! What I have not fully understand is: if I have $o(x^3)+x^2+x$ can I write this as equal to $o(x^2)+x^2+x$?

Comment: You can not use equality (in set sense), but you can write $o(x^3)+x^2+x \subset o(x^2)+x^2+x$ i.e. $f(x)=o(x^3)+x^2+x \Rightarrow f(x)=o(x^2)+x^2+x$. More exactly last is $f(x)\in o(x^3)+x^2+x \Rightarrow f(x) \in o(x^2)+x^2+x$